# Will Gmail still auto generate Trips card if I add Email Markup?

Tags: google-schemas

My company sends confirmation letter emails to end users for their reservations. Sometimes for Gmail users, the auto-generated Trips card gives the wrong information. For example, our email says Estes Park Campground at East Portal, but the card says Estes Park Campground at Mary's Lake.
Even though we argued that there was no problem with the actual email text, our clients still complained.
So is it possible to override the Trips card if we introduce Email Markup to generate an Event card on demand?